# How do I reverse an array in place in assembly?

Tags: assembly, masm

I am supposed to reverse an array in place. I have been working on it for a while and this is what I have. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
.data
array BYTE 10h, 20h, 30h, 40h

.code
main PROC
    mov esi, 0
    mov edi, 0
    mov esi, OFFSET array
    mov edi, OFFSET array + SIZEOF array
    mov ecx, SIZEOF array/2

l1: mov al, [esi]
    mov bl, [edi]
    mov [edi], al
    mov [esi], bl
    inc esi
    dec edi
    LOOP l1

    call DumpRegs
    call DumpMem

    exit

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Homework question? Anyway, you shouldn't initially place `edi` past the end of the array if you decrease *after* reading or writing.

Answer (score -1):

Try to declare two arrays, one intilized with your values and the other one could be like this using DUP operator 5 DUP (?)

And start moving values from first array to the second using a loop.

Example:

.data
myArr1 DWORD 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 
myArr2 DWORD 5 DUP (?)

.code main proc 
mov edi, offset myArr1 
add edi, sizeof myArr1 
mov esi, offset myArr2 
mov ecx, lengthof myArr2

reverseLoop: 
add ebx, [edi] mov[edi], ebx 
sub edi, type myArr2 
add esi, type myArr1 
mov eax, [edi] 
call writeint

LOOP reverseLoop

exit 
main endp 
end main

Comment: You mean as a baby-step towards doing it in-place?  The loop bounds are different when you're doing it in-place.  It's not like in-place is significantly more complicated, just different.

Comment: You should edit that into your answer if you think it's useful.  It's not going to help anyone as a comment with no formatting.